# Remove leading white space via Xpath expression

Tags: xml, xpath, jira

I have been searching for an answer to this, but have been unable to find the solution.

I have a call that returns an xml document. I dont have the ability to modify this document at all. Before the actual XML dump, there are 40 newlines and 1 tab. I would like to know, using an Xpath expression only, how do I ignore all of that white space and get directly to the nodes?

Example:

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<employees>
    <employee id="1">Johnny Dape</employee>
    <employee id="2">Al Pacino</employee>
    <employee id="3">Robert De Niro</employee>
    <employee id="4">Kevin Spacey</employee>
    <employee id="5">Denzel Washington</employee>
</employees>

Xpath expression: root/employee/  works as expected
```

but putting a ton of white space before it will cause it to not pull anything, as seen below

```
\n
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<employees>
    <employee id="1">Johnny Dape</employee>
    <employee id="2">Al Pacino</employee>
    <employee id="3">Robert De Niro</employee>
    <employee id="4">Kevin Spacey</employee>
    <employee id="5">Denzel Washington</employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: XPath has no interest in whitespace. To remove the leading whitespace you'd have to use XSLT's `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of whitespace immediately before the root element is of no consequence to most XPath expressions.  This includes `/root/employees` or `root/employees`.  Note that `root/employee`, as you originally posted, won't select anything.

Whitespace before an XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`) is prohibited.  In this case, you'll have to remove such whitespace in order to make the XML document be *well-formed*, a requirement for using XPath.  (Note that you must also close the `root` element – not shown in your posted XML.)

Comment: Ahh, I didnt close it in that example, but I dont have that issue in the actual document. So there is no way to use an expression in Xpath to remove that space?

Comment: XPath *selects* nodes.  It can *ignore* spaces, but in this case, spaces are irrelevant.  To ask if it can *remove* spaces is to misunderstand XPath's operation.

Comment: Alright. Then in that case, when there is white space before the declaration, how would one ignore the white space?

Comment: It is not an XML document if it has whitespace before the XML declaration.  You'll have to preprocess it as ***text***, remove it, and only then will you be able to use XML-based tools such as XPath on it.